# Why use escape in php for option value?

Tags: php, escaping

I have encountered this in my php code. It all works and everything but I don't understand why the escape needs to be used. This produces a drop down menu of all the months.

```
foreach ($months as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option value \"$key\">$value</option>\n";
```

But so does this:

```
foreach ($months as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option value $key>$value</option>\n";
```

So I am confused as to why the escape is used? Sorry this might be really obvious but I am new to php?

Comment: I can't see any difference between those snippets.

Comment: *"but so does this"* --- they're both exactly the same; am I missing something obvious? <= **A:** Nope; they're the same. You probably meant `echo '<option value "$key">$value</option>\n';` or `echo "<option value '$key'>$value</option>\n";` --- You're also missing an `=` sign for your value.

Comment: the escaping is for the double quote, to indicate that you want the double quote included in the string.

Comment: Sorry Mike you are right. My mistake. Well good going on detecting the no difference. I have now changed it.

Comment: @Flauntster It still makes no sense to me since the double quotes don't appear in the drop down menu?

Comment: @Danrex Have you tried the second one? It will fail and show you a relevant error message.

Comment: No it works just the same, they both show the exact same result

Comment: It is ***impossible*** that `echo "<option value "$key">$value</option>\n";` does not produce a parse error. Unescaped double quotes inside double quotes are a no no 100% of the time. It will never work unless you write your own PHP parser

Comment: @Danrex It's not very likely. Make sure you're not missing something in the second example.

Comment: You are both right. Please check again now. Sorry for the editing mistakes. When I take out the /" from either side of the $key it works. So whats the point in having them in?

Comment: They're syntax for HTML attributes, not for PHP. It's also supposed to become `<option value="id">` not `<tag attr literal>` without `=`. Doing it properly would also involve `htmlspecialchars` unless the keys were pre-asserted to contain alphanumeric string data only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example does not work; it produces a Parse Error.

The quotes are escaped to indicate to PHP that you want to literally return the quotes rather than using the quotes to indicate the beginning or end of a string.  In your first example, this works.  In your second example, an error is produced because you're missing an operator (like a `.` to indicate concatenation) both before and after the `$key` variable.

**UPDATE:** You've updated your question, so I'll update my answer accordingly.

The difference now is that in your first example the quotes will print around `$key`, and in the second example quotes will not print around `$key`.

If `$key` contains a value without spaces, then there is no functional difference to the browser, they'll both create the drop-down the same way.  But if `$key` contains spaces, this won't work correctly as only the characters before the space in `$key` will be sent as the value of the selected option.

Imagine the following HTML:

```
<option value="some value">Display</option>
```

Now without the quotes:

```
<option value=some value>Display</option>
```

Or with perhaps more attributes included:

```
<option value=some value selected>Display</option>
```

So you can see that this doesn't work.

Comment: You are correct. My bad. But when I take out the "/ on either side it works again. I understand what the / is doing and why, I just don't know why it would do that when I can just not include them in the first place and it does the same thing.

Comment: @Danrex I've updated my answer to match your updated question.

Comment: Ok so if I am reading you correctly. Although it works correctly for this particular example if I was to have something like \"This is a $key\" then the first example would be the one that would work and the second one would fall down like a house of cards? In other words it's just good practise?

Comment: @Danrex, sorta of.. if `$key == "This is a key"` (or any other value with spaces or characters that the browser parsed as the end of the string) and you passed `$key`, then it would fail.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks! I am learning php and couldn't understand the rationale behind having them there.